# External Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to create an external table in SQL Server 2019 but am getting the error

> Incorrect syntax near "external"

This is my DDL statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE exttest
(
   [summonsnumber] [varchar](max) NULL,
   [plateid] [varchar](500) NULL,
   [registrationstate] [varchar](500) NULL,
   [platetype] [varchar](500) NULL,
   [issuedate] [varchar](500) NULL
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = 'Parking.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = MyAzureStorage
)
GO
```

Comment: Is your database set to compatibility Level 150?

Comment: Do you have polybase installed/enabled? I.e. can you access the polybase folder on your server instance?

Comment: DB's compatiblity level is 150  and Polybase is installed